# Extending tibble: getting the new S3 class to stick

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

For [ropensci/drake#489](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/489), I would like to define a new print method for `tibbles` of class `"drake_plan"`. I read the [guide on extending `tibble`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/extending.html), which was helpful for some of the requirements. But the new `"drake_plan"` S3 class drops during `dplyr` operations.

```
#' @title Mark a data frame as a `drake` workflow plan
#' @description Used for pretty printing only (coming soon).
#'   You do not actually have to mark plans as such.
#'   You can keep them as ordinary data frames.
#' @export
#' @keywords internal
#' @param x object to mark as a `drake` plan
#' @param ... other arguments to the method
#' @examples
#' plan <- list(target = "x", command = "get_data()")
#' class(plan)
#' plan <- as_drake_plan(plan)
#' class(plan)
as_drake_plan <- function(x){
  UseMethod("as_drake_plan")
}

as_drake_plan_ <- function(x, ...){
  tibble::new_tibble(x, ..., subclass = "drake_plan")
}

#' @export
`[.drake_plan` <- function(...){
  as_drake_plan_(NextMethod())
}

#' @export
#' @rdname as_drake_plan
as_drake_plan.data.frame <- as_drake_plan_

#' @export
#' @rdname as_drake_plan
as_drake_plan.list <- as_drake_plan_

#' @export
#' @rdname as_drake_plan
as_drake_plan.tbl_df <- as_drake_plan_

library(dplyr)
library(drake)
plan <- drake_plan(
  x = get_data(),
  y = analyze_data(x)
) %>%
  as_drake_plan() %>%
  print
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   target command        
#> * <chr>  <chr>          
#> 1 x      get_data()     
#> 2 y      analyze_data(x)
class(plan)
#> [1] "drake_plan" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
filter(plan, target == "x") %>%
  class()
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

And besides `dplyr` functions, are there other situations that remove subclasses from `tibble`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The`tibble` package now has a `new_tibble()` constructor, which was also pointed out by @landau:

https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/new_tibble.html

```
# The nrow argument is always required:
new_tibble(list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), nrow = 3)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     4
#> 2     2     5
#> 3     3     6
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found that this is already documented on the `dplyr` development page: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2532. Apparently, there are no plans to try to preserve `tibble` subclasses.

Comment: I believe this answer is not correct anymore. Please take a look at https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/new_tibble.html

Comment: Yup, I agree. `new_tibble()` is the way to go. Answer and I will accept.

Comment: Did just that :) See below.